# ST_CONTAINS equivalent in MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, geometry, shapefile

Does MySQL 5.1 contains any ST_CONTAINS() equivalent function?

I have some Multi-polygon data stored in Geometry format and i want to check if it contains a POINT
The query would be like

```
select * from table_name 
WHERE column_name ST_CONTAINS(GeomFromText(POINT(-119.998450047337002 39.496199946739303)));
```

LIKE and REGXP queries returns empty result set.
MySQL 5.6 includes this function but i have 5.1 in live.
Sorry for any mistakes, I am a newbie for Geo Spatial Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved it, heres a new query

```
select * from table_name 
    WHERE column_name CONTAINS(
    GeomFromText(POINT(-119.998450047337002 39.496199946739303)
));
```

Comment: CONTAINS() actually doesn't work in MySQL 5.1. It just does a bounding rectangle around your polygon.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,286574,286574#msg-286574 has a much better way to do this.